# Bash - if...then statement - unexpected token

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm writing a script and want to check, that grep command found match. But all the time I receive unexpected token "else" error. Could you plese explain, where's the problem? I checked my syntax several times

I'm using Debian GNU/Linux version 8 (jessie)

```
#!/bin/bash
if monit status wildfly | grep -q "OK" ; then
  echo found
else
  echo not found
fi
```

Comment: but when I try to execute script all the tine I see:
" syntax error near unexpected token `else`"

Comment: Is your script perhaps larger than what you are showing? Is the above copy & paste or re-typed? Small things matter...

Comment: (Unrelated, but Debian 8 "jessie" is really, really old... 11 is current, 12 is in preview. Why are you using such an aged version?)

Comment: No, that's all, nothing else

Comment: Did you try something simpler, like `if true; then echo ok; else echo ko; fi`?

Comment: What is the output of `monit status wildfly`?

Comment: DOS line endings can cause this problem, as the "command" `then\r` is seen by the parser instead of the expected keyword `then`. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info, under "Before asking about problematic code".

Answer (score -1):

That syntax works in macOS using ZSH, guessing you're in Linux or using any other shell. Two suggestions:

- use the bulletproof syntax for `if`

```
if monit status wildfly | grep -q "OK"
then
  echo found
else
  echo not found
fi
```

- add a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the top of your script to use bash:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Comment: I did it all, thanks, but still the same situation:

```
!#/bin/bash

if monit status wildfly | grep -q "OK"
then
   echo found
else
   echo nope
fi
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more info in the question? OS you're using and Shell mainly?

Comment: @DiegoFreniche You suggest to add a shebang to use bash but the one you suggest is for sh. `#!/usr/bin/env bash` is probably better.

Comment: Hard-coding the actual path to `bash` is even better. You can't assume that the version of `bash` provided by a user's path is the version of `bash` your script requires. The *user* should set the shebang, not the script's author.

Comment: @chepner: The point is that some platforms have the binary at `/bin/bash`, others at `/usr/bin/bash`, and `#!/usr/bin/env bash` catches both.